# Sudden MySQL error (easyphp 12.1)

Tags: php, mysql, easyphp

I was creating my website when suddenly, after pressing a button on my website MySQL stopped working. I've already tried restarting my pc, it still stops working when I start MySQL. It is weird because the last button I pressed shouldn't have changed anything on MySQL.

The code:

```
    <form target="_blank" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?id=KlientoInfoKeitimas&elpastas=<?php echo $elpastas ?>" method="post">
    El. paštas: <input type="text" name="elpastas"><br>
    Slaptažodis: <input type="text" name="slaptazodis"><br>
    Vardas: <input type="text" name="vardas"><br>
    Pavardė: <input type="text" name="pavarde"><br>
    Telefonas: <input type="text" name="telefonas"><br>
    Slaptažodis: <input type="text" name="slaptazodis"><br>
    Lytis: 
    <select name="lytis">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Vyras</option>
    <option value="2">Moteris</option>
    </select><br>
    Adresas: <input type="text" name="adresas"><br>
    <input class="registruoti" type="submit" name="submit" value="Pakeisti" />`
```

The code after submit (there shouldn't be any problems with the MySQL connection, so I'm not copying it):

```
    if (isset($_POST['elpastas'])) {
        $elpastas = $_POST['elpastas'];
        $pakeistalaukeliu++;
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE klientas SET el_pastas='$elpastas' WHERE kliento_id='$klientoid'");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['slaptazodis'])) {
        $slaptazodis = $_POST['slaptazodis'];
        $pakeistalaukeliu++;
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE klientas SET slaptazodis='$slaptazodis' WHERE kliento_id='$klientoid'");

        ...the same with every input...

        mysqli_close($con);
```

I might have found a solution. I turned off both Apache and MySQL, pasted an old ibdata1 file, started MySQL, and Apache. After some time I turned them off, pasted ibdata1 (the one that I had the error with), started MySQL and then Apache. It's still working.

I'm guessing that I was receiving those errors because MySQL was not shut down properly and after I did it, everything worked fine. Anyway, if anyone knows what has been made wrong to make this error happen, or what mistakes I have made, please post your answers.

Comment: The error seems self explanatory to me. Something is corrupt. Your best bet (since using InnoDB anyway) is to take the database file out, reinstall mysql, and to put your database back in.

Comment: Are there any guides how to do it properly?

Comment: You're using MySQLi but not using prepared statements? And not even escaping your inputs?